# How to change the subtotal in PowerBi from sum to average?

Tags: powerbi

I have created a Matrix in PowerBI. The total is the sum. How can I change sum to average?

Now I need to create another table to calculate the average.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the 'Total' to Average. If you want it to display sum of the average quantity, then go to the `Values Option` in `Fields` and click on the dropdown. Then select `Average`. See this:

[image: Dropdown]